# Couldn't install Virtual Box on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox

I am trying to install Virtual Box in my Ubuntu 14.04 Box. I downloaded the package file from official website [here](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.0/virtualbox-5.1_5.1.0-108711~Ubuntu~trusty_amd64.deb)

I tried installing this package but it is throwing errors. Below is the information reported in terminal-

```
ravi@Dell:~$ sudo dpkg -i Downloads/virtualbox-5.1_5.1.0-108711-Ubuntu-trusty_amd64.deb 
[sudo] password for ravi: 
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-5.1.
(Reading database ... 440671 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox-5.1_5.1.0-108711-Ubuntu-trusty_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-5.1 (5.1.0-108711~Ubuntu~trusty) ...
Setting up virtualbox-5.1 (5.1.0-108711~Ubuntu~trusty) ...
Adding group `vboxusers' (GID 125) ...
Done.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.13-1) ...
```

Below are the few lines from the bottom of `dmesg` command-

```
[   85.053851] wlan0: AP advertised VHT without HT, disabling both
[   85.060656] wlan0: send auth to 18:64:72:1d:51:50 (try 1/3)
[   85.061293] wlan0: authenticated
[   85.064889] wlan0: associate with 18:64:72:1d:51:50 (try 1/3)
[   85.065625] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 18:64:72:1d:51:50 (capab=0x11 status=0 aid=5)
[   85.067183] wlan0: associated
[   85.071714] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: JP
[   85.071723] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[   85.071725] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[   85.071729] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   85.071731] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   85.071734] cfg80211:   (4910000 KHz - 4990000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2300 mBm), (N/A)
[   85.071736] cfg80211:   (5030000 KHz - 5090000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2300 mBm), (N/A)
[   85.071739] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[   85.071742] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[   85.071744] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2300 mBm), (0 s)
[   85.165436] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 23 (23 - 0) dBm as advertised by 18:64:72:1d:51:50
[  372.263572] capability: warning: `VirtualBox' uses 32-bit capabilities (legacy support in use)
[  702.263467] systemd-hostnamed[9090]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!
[  852.612307] perf interrupt took too long (2510 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
```

Comment: Please try to find `vboxdrv` in `dmesg` output and paste that part into the question.

Comment: No such message available. `dmesg |grep vboxdrv ` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable Secure Boot in BIOS settings.

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-dkms-modules) for more details.

The `vboxdrv` is not signed and Secure Boot does not let to load it.

Comment: `You need to disable Secure Boot in BIOS settings`. It was working earlier but suddenly stopped after installing some updates. Hence I thought of reinstalling it. Let me check the reference link. I'll get back to you shortly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried `sudo mokutil --disable-validation` but again `vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.`

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS and reboot.

Comment: That worked beautifully. But is it recommended to disabled `Secure Boot `? I am little hesitating by doing it.

Comment: Secure Boot is a useless Microsoft feature IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

You should prefer the version maintained by Ubuntu [APT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool) unless you have special needs. Install VirtualBox using APT:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

Comment: The VirtualBox repository is well-maintained and comes directly from the developers; there is no reason to discourage its use.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install virtualbox` I tried this command too. I got the same error message `vboxdrv.sh: failed: modprobe vboxdrv failed. Please use 'dmesg' to find out why.` . Later on I thought of downloading the latest package from the official website, instead of using `apt-get` but unfortunately, it didn't work either.